# Flags displaying as a string in Polylang

Tags: wordpress-theming, polylang

I'm building a custom WordPress theme and want to make it compatible with Polylang but I get issue when testing the language switcher with flags. My Theme uses bootstrap and the menu uses the Bootstrap NavWalker Menu

Here is what I get instead of the image flag:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Français" width="16" height="11" style="width: 16px; height: 11px;" /><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Français</span>
```

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a base64 encoded image that you receive. And it should be displayed correctly on frontend.

See this https://codepen.io/hug0-drelon/pen/eYWaMVX with `<img src="data:image/png;base64, <!--encoded image--> " alt="Français" width="16" height="11" style="width: 16px; height: 11px;" /><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Français</span>` for instance.